# How do you copy text from qpython console?

Tags: qpython

I would like to copy the console output to ask a question about a program that's not working. but it seems the normal way of holding down text doesn't highlight the text for selection like in the editor.

Is there a way to copy the text from qpython console?

Answer (score 0):

You can only press-and-hold the console and then select the "Copy All" option.
At least I am doing so.
I think there is no way to copy specific text.